# Does this look like a DDOS attack?

Tags: http, ddos, aws

I've put up a small proof of concept web api on AWS infrastructure (elastic beanstalk) using their free tier. My app is working fine, but I'm seeing a lot of this in the access logs:

```
172.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [18/Jun/2017:10:18:59 +0000] "POST /device/enabler/linear HTTP/1.1" 403 362 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "149.100.171.172"
172.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [18/Jun/2017:10:18:59 +0000] "POST /device/enabler/linear HTTP/1.1" 403 362 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "2.227.202.134"
172.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [18/Jun/2017:10:18:59 +0000] "POST /device/enabler/linear HTTP/1.1" 403 362 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "93.44.33.132"
172.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [18/Jun/2017:10:18:59 +0000] "POST /device/enabler/linear HTTP/1.1" 403 362 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "93.37.77.196"
172.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [18/Jun/2017:10:18:59 +0000] "POST /device/enabler/linear HTTP/1.1" 403 362 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "151.62.133.102"
172.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [18/Jun/2017:10:18:59 +0000] "POST /device/enabler/linear HTTP/1.1" 403 362 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "95.249.219.42"
172.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [18/Jun/2017:10:18:59 +0000] "POST /device/enabler/linear HTTP/1.1" 403 362 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "2.34.37.138"
```

I'm seeing about 7 hits per second, and it's always a `POST` to `/device/enabler/linear`.  The URL is not part my app at all.  I've reverse DNS'ed some of the IP's, and they all seem to be from Italian ISPs (not sure if that is relevant).

It's not a massive issue at the moment as it's not preventing my app working (so not really sure if it counts as a ddos?), but it is a nuisance, and it has caused me to take the service down (so arguably has succeeded).  And it will start to cost me money at some point because the access logs are being written to much faster than I anticipated so I will exceed the S3 puts that are in the free plan.

I'm in the process of working out how to configure the AWS EC2 firewall stuff (I think that's what I need to configure to allow access access from my client)

Has anyone seen this type of thing before? Could it be a ddos? has anyone seen hits to this url like this (I've googled for it and drawn a blank)

Appreciate any advice anyone can offer;

Comment: What's the payload of those requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's not a massive issue at the moment as it's not preventing my app
>   working (so not really sure if it counts as a ddos?)

**let's state some definitions**

Denial of service : If service has not been denied by the attack, It's not DoS nor DDoS. It might be abusive, but that wouldn't be quite the same stuff.

**Assumption**

- 93.44.33.132, 2.227.202.134, 93.37.77.196, 151.62.133.102, 95.249.219.42 and 2.34.37.138 have a negative reputation, says [symantec](http://ipremoval.sms.symantec.com/lookup/).
- Regarding a DDoS attack, 7 requests per second are not a lot. The post request size might be a hint. For instance if the size is greater than 1 Mo, yes, it **can** be a DDoS attempt.
- The numbers 403 and 362. Assuming those numbers is a response code, it looks like your app is denying the access with a 403 Forbidden, 362 may state why the access is forbidden. ***<- i might be wrong with this point.***
- So what do we have ? We know that some low reputation IP are making 7 POST request / sec. On a URL that doesn't exist. From my experience, we do not have enough info to determine if this pattern is a DDoS attack. We have to go deeper.

**Going deeper**

For further investigation, i will start by fetching three entire post requests and their responses (with different source IP).

the goal is to:

- Know the size of the 3 requests/responses.
- Find any payload in the request's header or content.
- what data those requests are posting.
- what are the responses and how your app handle those requests.

**Not in the question range**

Knowing if a reverse proxy is present between the client and the app might be interesting too. For instance, those requests might target the proxy and not the app, for cache poisoning purpose.

Comment: Good points, except symantec rep system has a bad rep. :D

Comment: Technically, since the OP had to disable service due to the issue, it's strictly speaking a Denial of Service. What it might not have been though, is that it's most likely not an intentional DoS. From the look of it, this could have been a misconfigured load balancer/appliance/IoT device looking up a service that was previously hosted in the domain name or IP address that the OP currently owns. The OP might want to check historical record of their Domain name and IP address. You might also want to check the Host header of these requests.

Comment: Symantec's reputation determination appears to be based on the same source as Spamhaus Database. All the IP addresses that Symantec claims to have "negative" reputation are in Spamhaus PBL (Policy Block List), but are not in SBL nor XBL. Being in PBL does not indicate that the IP address have ever misbehaved. An IP address is usually in the PBL because the IP range is allocated for residential uses, so by default it's assumed to not be permitted to send mail without authentication.

Comment: @LieRyan Thanks for sharing, didn't know about that. Any IP reputation lookup suggestion ?

Comment: I don't have recommendations, personally I don't see anything particularly bad with Symantec's ip rep (as long as you take into account the reasons for its determination, to decide whether that determination applies in your particular situation). @Overmind might have more specific reasons of why he doesn't trust Symantec's tool.

Comment: Interestingly terminating the environment and restarting it 24 hours later seems to have fixed the problem! No more mysterious requests! @Baptiste, thanks for your comprehensive answer, some really useful info there for diagnosing it next time, so I'll mark you answer as the one that fixed it. Thanks

Comment: In the standard webserver log format, the "362" is the size, in bytes, of the response sent by the server.

Comment: @Lie Ryan BLs cannot be evaluated all together. Some are balanced, some are way over-excessive in many situations (like sorbs).

Comment: @Nathan Russell: that sounds like DNS propagation delay or if AWS assigned you a different IP address after restarts, then it's probably some other poor bloke that are now receiving the misdirected requests.